# Java OpenGL 2d Image Rotating

Tags: java

I want to rotate a 2d texture in OpenGL (lwjgl) using glRotatef, but i dont understand how it works. I've seen many posts but i cant get it working.
This is my code:

```
    GL11.glRotatef(180, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x,p.getPosition().y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth(),p.getPosition().y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth(),p.getPosition().y+playerTexture.getTextureHeight());
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x,p.getPosition().y+playerTexture.getTextureHeight());
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Comment: So where and how have you tried adding `glRotatef`? please show your attempts

Comment: Also the [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) states what each parameter means - where exactly are you having issues?

Comment: GL11.glRotatef(rquad,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

Comment: rquad -= 0.15f;

Comment: I'm having isssues just trying to rotate the whole thing, i dont understand the wiki page i already took a look at it, what do they mean with the vector of x y z

Comment: `x` `y` and `z` are the coordinate axes - you can google "OpenGL coordinate axes" for a graphical representation and more explanations. Since you are working in 2D space you most likely want to rotate around the `z` axis, so you should try `GL11.glRotatef(rquad, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);`

Comment: Oh thanks, and how would i go about turning it from its center?

Comment: All rotations happen around the center of the coordinate system, so you would first have to place your object in the center, then rotate and then move (translate) it to where you want it to be.

Comment: Oh and what do they mean with angle?

Comment: You mean in `glRotatef`? The documentation say: *"Specifies the angle of rotation, in degrees."* - so how much you want to rotate by

Comment: I have tried this now:
        GL11.glRotatef(180, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x,p.getPosition().y);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
            GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth(),p.getPosition().y);
            GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
            GL11.glVertex2f(p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth(),p.getPosition().y+playerTexture.getTextureHeight());

Comment: But it simply starts flashing

Comment: please edit relevant code into the actual question - it's really hard to read in the comments (and most people will miss it as well)

Comment: Okay i edited it.